# Does a closed unbounded operator commutes with Riemann integral?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, unbounded-operators

Let $A$ be an unbunded operator with densely domain $D(A)$ in a Hilbert space $H$.

Is it true that $A$ commutes with Riemann integral? that is :

For any Riemann  integrable function $f : [a,b] \to H$ such that $f(x)\in D(A),\; \forall x\in [a,b],$ we have:
$$
A\int_a^b f(x) dx=\int_a^b Af(x) dx
$$

Comment: Why should $Af$ be integrable?

Comment: I think, this is the main problem, since if we show that $Af$ is integrable, then we can replace $A$ with  $\lambda R(\lambda;A) A \in {\cal L}(H)$ (where $R(\lambda;A)$ is the resolvent of $A$) and then use the dominated convergence theorem to pass to $\lambda \to+\infty.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example, let $f(x) = \chi_{[a,x]}$, which defines a continuous function from $[a,b]$ into $H=L^2[a,b]$. Then
$$
       \left.\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx\right|_{t} = \int_{t}^{b}dx=(b-t).
$$
The resulting function is nicely differentiable. You can consider $A=\frac{d}{dt}$ on the dense domain $\mathcal{D}(A)$ consisting of all absolutely continuous $f \in L^2$ for which $f' \in L^2$. That defines a closed densely-defined operator $A$ for which $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx \in \mathcal{D}(A)$, but such that $f(x) \notin \mathcal{D}(A)$ for all $a < x < b$.

If $f(x) \in \mathcal{D}(A)$ is Riemann integrable, and if $Af(x)$ is also Riemann integrable, then
$$
        A\sum_{\mathscr{P}}f(x_j^*)\Delta x_j=\sum_{\mathscr{P}}(Af)(x_j^*)\Delta x_j,
$$
and both sides converge as $\|\mathscr{P}\|\rightarrow 0$. The result follows as you want because $A$ is closed and
$$
         \sum_{\mathscr{P}}f(x_j^*)\Delta x_j\rightarrow \int_a^b f(x)dx, \\
       A\sum_{\mathscr{P}}f(x_j^*)\Delta x_j \rightarrow \int_a^b (Af)(x)dx.
$$
The above then shows that $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx \in \mathcal{D}(A)$ and
$$
          A\left(\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx\right) = \int_{a}^{b}(Af)(x)dx.
$$

Comment: But, by hypothsesis, I supposed that $f$ is s.t: $f(x)\in D(A)$ for all $x\in [a,b]$.

Comment: @Rabat : In this case, $f(x) \notin\mathcal{D}(A)$ because of the discontinuity. However, the integral is in $\mathcal{D}(A)$. So you can't interchange application of $A$ with the integral.

Comment: Perhaps, my first question wasn't clear. An other way to ask the same question: are there any function $f$ such that $f(x)\in D(A),\, \forall x\in [a,b],$ but $A\int_a^b f(x) dx \ne \int_a^b A f(x) dx$.

Comment: @Rabat : You'll need more: You'll need that $Af(x)$ is Riemann integrable, for example. That should be sufficient.

Comment: Yes, I see now. Thanks

Comment: @Rabat : I added the explanation to my answer.